# In-app product - FormattedPrice with many decimal places

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I implemented in-app purchases inside universal app and for testing I use my own XML file with list of in-app products. On Windows 8.1 it works very well but on Windows Phone 8.1 [FormattedPrice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.productlisting.formattedprice(v=win.10).aspx) property is returning price with many decimal places. Am I able to somehow fix it because it looks really strange?

Sample: http://1drv.ms/1yVNhRw

[image]

```
<Product ProductId="product2" ProductType="Consumable">
  <MarketData xml:lang="de-de">
    <Name>Product Title 2</Name>
    <Price>49.99</Price>
    <CurrencySymbol>€</CurrencySymbol>
  </MarketData>
</Product>

<Product ProductId="product1" ProductType="Consumable">
  <MarketData xml:lang="de-de">
    <Name>Product Title 1</Name>
    <Price>8.99</Price>
    <CurrencySymbol>€</CurrencySymbol>
  </MarketData>
</Product>
```

Comment: Can you try to parse it: `decimal price = decimal.Parse(storeProduct.FormattedPrice, NumberStyles.Currency);`?

Comment: @Romasz: For "€8.990000" it returns 8990000. I was trying to experiment with NumberStyles but I wasn't successful.

Comment: Try to play with culture, the third parameter of decimal.Parse() method.

Comment: @Romasz: Without success, I have added sample into my original message.

Comment: The problem is that in de-DE culture, decimal separator is `,` not `.` - you may run a short test: `decimal priceTest2 = Decimal.Parse(product.FormattedPrice.Replace('.',','), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`

Comment: @Romasz It works, but is it usable for all languages?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it will work will all languages. I also don't know why the price for de-DE was set with `.` separator. You may also try to make use of *CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator*.

Comment: @Romasz Probably it was waste of time to find solution because in the Store it works properly. There is just a problem with XML file...